# Traversing the perimeter of a 2D array counterclockwise

Tags: c, arrays

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so please let me know if I am not following the community guidelines and conventions correctly.

What is a clever way to traverse the perimeter of a 2D array in a counterclockwise (or clockwise) direction from `row 0`, `column 0` (preferably without revisiting each element)?

Intuitively, I could write four `for` loops for each direction sequentially (i.e., write a `for` loop to traverse the left column, then write a `for` loop to traverse the bottom row, and so forth). But this solution feels "hard-coded".

Does there exist a "shortcut" method that takes advantage of some key insight on this pattern? Would this shortcut method also be efficient in terms of program runtime?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit for specificity:

Specifically, I am trying to traverse this 2D array counterclockwise from `row 0`, `column 0`, and print each element only once.

Suppose the array looks like this:
`01 02 03 04 05
 06 07 08 09 10
 11 12 13 14 15
 16 17 18 19 20`

My intended output is as follows:
`1, 6, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 15, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2`.

Here is my current solution (this solution works):

```
//Loop through the left side.
int i;
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    printf("%d, ", array[i][0]);

//Loop through the bottom side.
for (i = 1; i < columns; i++)
    printf("%d, ", array[rows-1][i]);

//Loop through the right side.
for (i = rows-2; i >= 0; i--)
    printf("%d, ", array[i][columns-1]);

//Loop through the top side.
for (i = columns-2; i > 1; i--)
    printf("%d, ", array[0][i]);

//Print the last element.
printf("%d.\n", array[0][1]);
```

Personally, my solution seems straightforward and repetitive. I would like to know if there is a more creative solution.

Please let me know if any more clarification is needed.

Comment: Hard coded? What other shape would a 2-D array be? It's only hard-coded if you don't use variables (or perhaps `#define`) to control the loop limits.

Comment: You are not following the community guidelines and conventions correctly.  How about consulting the handy [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), which tells you all about what kinds of questions you can ask and advises you about how to ask them?  Among other things, you will find that we expect questions about *specifc* problems (yours isn't), preferably that can be demonstrated with a [mcve].  Broad questions that boil down to "I don't know how to approach the problem" tend not to be well received.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hi, thanks for replying back! I mean that the structure of the code seems repetitive.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Should I include my code? I'm simply looking for a unique or clever solution to this problem.

Comment: @FridaySky coding can be very repetetive. Depending on why you are circumnavigating a 2D array, you might only need two loops, one for each pair of edges.

Comment: If you want to pose a specific question about the code you've written -- for example, about why it isn't behaving as you expect it to do, then yes, post a [mcve] version of your code.  But what you seem to be asking is not a question of a type that we generally field here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I think the four loops you described as "hard coded" are honestly the best and clearest solution. That said, here are two options in one loop for an array[N][M]:

```
for(int row = 0, col = 0, i = 0; i < 4;) {
  //process
  switch(i) {
    case 0: 
      if(++row == N)
        ++i;
      break;
    case 1: 
      if(++col == M)
        ++i; 
      break;
    case 2: 
      if(--row == 0)
        ++i;
      break;
    case 3:
      if(--col == 0)
        ++i;
      break;
  }
}
```

OR

```
int dirs[][] = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}};

for(int row = 0, col = 0, i = 0; i < 4;) {
  //process
  if( dirs[i][0] && ((row += dirs[i][0]) == 0 || row == N) ||
      dirs[i][1] && ((col += dirs[i][1]) == 0 || col == M))
    ++i;
}
```

NOTE: All comparisons to 0 can be replaced by a negation. `(a == 0) == (!a)` for all integer types.

#### Explanation:

Both solutions take advantage of the idea of traveling in a direction until you hit a max/min, and incrementing a counter to track state. One uses a switch statement to process the state, and the other uses an array in memory. For the second solution, we only switch state if the thing we are changing (either row or col) hits a max or a min. We don't care if the one changing by 0 is at a max or min, that doesn't change state.

I will reiterate though, the best solution is to use the four loops you mentioned, and to avoid duplication, call a function within each loop.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt! I don't have 15 reputation yet, so I can't upvote your answer. But I did mark your answer as the best.